# Encode data from String to bytes for HTTBody in NSData Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm developing a gateway link to a bank in which to enter the credit card number, make a payment to prove that the credit card is correct. Android I have no problem but in iOS with Swift I don't get it to work. Currently I have a String that is the thing I have to send the URL, the problem is that this PostData Bytes must be in base64, but failed to convert it.

This is what I have in Android:

> `EncodingUtils.getBytes(mstrPostData, "base64")`

This take the String and convert to Bytes in base64 encoding.

I need the same with Swift and after converted, put inside a NSData to assign in HTTBody from my Request Object

EDIT: I solved the problem with these:

```
let utf8str: NSData = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

let base64Encoded: String = utf8str.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

let data: NSData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64Encoded as String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))!
```

Another error I found is a parameter that I put inside postString is SHA1 and one of the values was incorrect.

Comment: Did you look up the NSData documentation? There *are* Base64 related methods ...

Comment: what you have in android does not work... (because base64 is not a string encoding, it's a byte[] encoding)

Comment: @njzk2 I use these method:                                                                     public static byte[] getBytes(String data, String charset) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://iosdevelopertips.com/swift-code/base64-encode-decode-swift.html seems to offer something you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS7+, you can use the built-in method of NSData:

```
NSString *string = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];
```

if mstrPostData is an NSString, you can convert to NSData:

```
NSData* data = [mstrPostData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

this is Objective-C code